# Google Cloud startup-script

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

I am running Jupyter Notebook on a virtual machine on Google Cloud. Whenever I start the VM I have to start the process manually in the shell:

```
nohup jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser
```

I want this process to run automatically whenever the VM is started, so I tried to add the following script in the VM properties under "Custom metadata" startup-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
nohup jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser
```

This doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this command to your /etc/rc.local

Edit the /etc/rc.local as superUser with Vim for example and add

```
nohup /full/path/jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser
```

You can get the full path like this: *(example)*

```
user@host:~$ which jupyter
  /usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: I added the command to /etc/rc.local using sudo nano /etc/rc.local
Somehow it still doesn't work, I've tried with sudo and I've also tried excluding nohup.

Current rc.local script:
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
nohup jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser
exit 0

Comment: try adding the full path to the jupyter binary. You can get this path with "which" command. I edit my Answer to put an example