# GCP not runnig startup script : npm start with nohup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I am using nextjs for server side rendering and using GCP for deployement.
I have added these command in gcp startup script but npm start is not working

experiment 1

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 60; cd /root/path/; nohup npm start &
```

experiment 2

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 60

cd /root/path/

nohup npm start &
```

please guide me where I am missing.

Comment: also tried the way which mention in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809851/google-cloud-startup-script 

nothing is working. please guide me someone

Answer (score 1):

Try running it like this

```
nohup npx next start &
```

Comment: tried it but this didn't solve our problem